# How to add elements during for_each

Tags: c++, stl

I'm attempting to do a *conditional add*:

```
std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(),[&](Foo p){
    if (p.passesSomeTest()){
        p.change();
        foos.push_back(p);
    }
});
```

Basically, I have a list of elements, and using those elements, if they fit certain conditions, I want to create a copy of them, modify it a bit, and then add it to the same list.

I do not need my `for_each` to check the newly-added elements.

Is there any way to do this using the stl?

Comment: It is unwise to modify the vector while you are iterating over it. `push_back` may invalidate all iterators. I'm too lazy to dig through the standard at the moment, but I would be surprised if your code doesn't exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: It`s bad idea modify container while you use it in loop. Because if you modify list your iterators become incorrect.

Comment: Personally, I'd just have a hand-written loop, based on indexes rather than iterators.

Comment: Boost::container provides an implementation of `stable_vector` which may actually tolerate this sort of abuse.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @Guinness I understand that this is not the way to do i.  I know of the `remove_if`, and so I was curious if there was a counterpart as conditional add.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's what I ended up doing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary list to make it easier

```
std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(),[&](Foo p){
    if (p.passesSomeTest()){
        p.change();
        foos2.push_back(p);  // insert to temporary foos2 list
    }
});

foos.insert(foos.end(), foos2.begin(), foos2.end());  // insert temporary list to foos
```

Comment: Using [splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) avoids per-element copying. (+1)